# How can I add an Array into a Queue?

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, queue

Is it possible to add an array into specifically, a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`? If so, how exactly would the `.add` statement look like?

**THIS IS HOMEWORK RELATED**, however, my entire program is meant to perform calculations on `MyObjects` (the default constructor of `MyObjects` generates random values to perform a ton of calculations on).

For example:

```
//Note: I couldn't use the Diamond Braces for the Queue-type when posing this question

ConcurrentLinkedQueue theLinkedQueue {MyObjects[]} = 
                 new ConcurrentLinkedQueue{MyObjects[]}();

MyObjects[] theArray = null;

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
   theArray = new MyObjects[CONSTANT_SIZE]; 
   theLinkedQueue.add(theArray(objparameter1, objparameter2));
}
```

The program implements *multi-threading* and in my thread class I've passed the `Queue` into the `constructor`, and am attempting to take off a `MyObject` array which a `MyObject` temp will point to, but so far I'm only capable of adding a single `MyObject` to my `Queue` at a time and pulling it. I want to be able to add the same amount of `MyObjects` as individual components rather than individually. I've attempted various lines of code only for *NetBeans IDE* to recommend a method to throw an `UnsupportedOperation Exception`. How could I add arrays into my `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`?

(Also apologies if my question is dense or confusing, first time posting here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for the declaration of your queue is:

```
ConcurrentLinkedQueue<MyObjects> theLinkedQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
```

Start with that and see how things go from there.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution, which was simply to add the array without 'objparameters' included.

```
theLinkedQueue.add(a);  //where a was a 'MyObject' array.
```

I presumed you had to load the parameter to be passed for each array index, which seems pretty silly.